# Why I get this error FUNCTION world.next_val does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, last_name, email) values (next_val('employee_seq'), 'John', 'Warton', 'warton@gmail.com');
```

I get this Error when running the project:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION world.next_val does not exist

Comment: Which database are you using? Have you tried `nextval('employee_seq')`?

Answer (score 0):

What's the database you are using and the id is stored with what datatype? If its UUID, you can try SYS_GUID().

```
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, last_name, email) values 
(SYS_GUID(), 'John', 'Warton', 'warton@gmail.com');
```